# Alternate way to group complete a homotopy commutative topological monoid

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Let $M$ be a topological monoid that is homotopy commutative.  I've been trying to understand the proof of the group completion theorem from [Hatcher's notes](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/Papers/MW.pdf).  Roughly speaking, this theorem says that the homology of $\Omega B M$ can be obtained from the graded ring $H_{\bullet}(M)$ by localizing at $\pi_0(M)$.

When $\pi_0(M)$ is finitely generated by elements $\{s_1,\ldots,s_m\}$, the model for this localization used in the above notes is the infinite telescope of the map $M \rightarrow M$ induced by multiplying by $t=s_1 \cdots s_m$.

This is not quite what I expected.  The group completion of a discrete commutative monoid $N$ equals $N_{\text{gc}} = (N \times N) / N$, where $N$ acts diagonally.  The completion map $N \rightarrow N_{\text{gc}}$ is the map taking $n \in N$ to the image of $(1,n)$ in $N_{\text{gc}}$.  Since we're working in the homotopy category, it makes sense to replace the quotient by some kind of homotopy quotient and define $M_{\text{gc}}$ to be the homotopy quotient of $M \times M$ by $M$, which I suppose should be the simplicial space $(EM \times M \times M)/M$, where $M$ acts diagonally.

This brings me to my questions: first, is the homology of $M_{\text{gc}}$ the same as that of $\Omega B M$, and second, can we use $M_{\text{gc}}$ in place of the infinite telescope in the proof of the group completion theorem?  The first question might have a positive answer without the giving a positive answer to the second question if you need the group completion theorem to calculate the homology of $M_{\text{gc}}$.

Assuming this actually works, it would have the advantage of not requiring the choice of a generating set (and also working when $\pi_0(M)$ is not finitely generated).

Comment: Not an answer, but a clarification: The reason the telescope construction is often used is because the only input one needs is the homology of the underlying space one started with and some knowledge about $\pi_0$ of the space. This is good enough to characterize some of the standard examples (Say for the groupoid of finite sets, one computes the homology of the infinite symmetric group). Your construction doesn't seem to have good computational properties at a first glance: To compute its homology one would need to apply the homotopy colimit spectral sequence and the Künneth theorem.

Comment: For strictly commutative topological monoids, one can actually get a model for $\Omega BM$ (under some additional weak hypotheses) as a quotient of $M\times M$. This was shown by Paulo Lima Filho in his thesis.

Comment: The paper is Completions and Fibrations for Topological Monoids, and it looks like you can access it here: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/245727815_Completions_and_Fibrations_for_Topological_Monoids

Comment: @DanRamras: Thanks!  I'll check that paper out.

Comment: It is worth noting that your proposed model of the group completion does not have a natural multiplication unless you start with a strictly commutative monoid. That should probably make one skeptical that it agrees with the usual notion of group completion.

Comment: @ConnorMalin: I'm not sure I understand.  Unless I'm making a mistake, its $k$-simplices are ordered sequences $[(m,m'),(m m_1,m' m_1),\ldots,(m m_1 \cdots m_k,m' m_1 \cdots m_k)$ where $(m,m') \in M \times M$ and $m_1,\ldots,m_k \in M$.  This has a perfectly good left action by $M$ which for $x \in M$ takes $(m,m')$ to $(m,x m')$.

Comment: I am saying that I would not expect the resulting quotient to have a natural multiplication for the same reason that you can't form the group completion of a noncommutative monoid as $M \times M / \Delta$. Generally homotopy commutativity does not behave very similar to actual commutativity

Comment: @ConnorMalin: Now I understand what you're saying.  I don't think the infinite telescope construction has a natural multiplication without strict commutativity either, but this does not prevent it from being homology equivalent to the group completion.

Comment: Ah I see now you weren't asking that this is actually the group completion just homology equivalent; that does make what I said less of a concern.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently working on a project (joint with di Fraia and Ramzi) that constructs a generalization of the question you have in mind. In particular, the following is true:

If $M$ is an $E_2$-monoid in spaces, which is just a little bit more structure than being homotopy-commutative, we can form a monoidal $\infty$-category $\mathbf{B}M$, which has a single object and mapping space given by $M$, and consider the functor $\mathbf{B}M \rightarrow \text{Spc}$, that represents the left action of $M$ on the product $M \times M$. We show that the colimit of this functor (but be aware, this is an $\infty$-categorical colimit!), i.e. $(M \times M)_{hM}$, is equivalent to the group completion of $M$.

So in some sense, you don't just get something homology equivalent, but even a space that completely models the group completion, if you're willing to work $\infty$-categorically.